# Php and AngularJs - getting data

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am creating simple request for GET a "message" with title etc from MySQL server.

So, I've got something like this in my AngularJS:

```
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost/webpack/downloadMessage.php',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log("CHECKED");
            console.log(response.data);
        }, function(response) {
            alert('something wrong');
        })
        })
        }
```

Just a request for data. But I'm confused with my php code, because I'm a beginner, can you help me what's wrong? I want just whole table where section = 3.

```
<?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(!isset($_POST)) die();

session_start();

$response = [];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'projekt');

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE section='3'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo json_encode($result);
```

It's without errors, but in my console i've got this:

> CHECKED {current_field: null, field_count: null, lengths: null,
> num_rows: null, type: null}

Comment: First, try to call directly through the browser the downloadMessage.php, and did you check the return of query using a mysql client?

Comment: `mysqli_query` does not return result you expect. `fetch_` functions do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) result of `mysqli_query` is either a `mysql_result` or `false` if query fails.

To get data from `mysqli_result` you need to **fetch** it, for example with [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo json_encode($row);
```

Also, there can be cases when you have **no** results (`$row` will be empty) or your query **fails** (`$result` will be `false`). These cases should be checked in your script and appropriate response should be returned.

Comment: Thank you very much :) of course, I know about validations, just wanted to get all, now I can code this :)